# Google Apps Scripts - MSWord to String

Tags: google-apps-script

When I attempt to run the following code (Output will be XML):

```
function doGet(e){
  return getFilesHtml();
}

function getFilesHtml() {
  //Create second to top level XML parent
  var xml = XmlService.createElement('response');

  try{
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('ANNOUNCEMENTS.doc');

    //Iterate through files and push to an array
    var filesarray = new Array();  
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      filesarray.push(files.next());
    }

    var file = getNewestFile(filesarray);

    //Create necessary XML elements and information
    var file_content = XmlService.createElement('content').setText(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('UTF-8'));
    xml.addContent(file_content);
  }catch(error){
    var stat_child = XmlService.createElement('status').setText('failure');
    var message_child = XmlService.createElement('message').setText(error.message);
    xml.addContent(stat_child);
    xml.addContent(message_child);
  }   

  //Prepare and respond with XML
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(xml);
  var xml2 = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  //Return the XML
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(xml2).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
}

function getNewestFile(array){
  array.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.getDateCreated()) - new Date(a.getDateCreated());
  });
  return array[0];
}
```

I get the following failure response:

```
<response>
  <status>failure</status>
  <message>
    We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
  </message>
</response>
```

My ultimate goal is to get the contents of this file. I've tried .getAs('application/pdf'), but that works not, like this. Is there any other method or a method to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." indicates that something went wrong deep within Apps Script. You'll have to troubleshoot the problem further before you can get help, and the [Apps Script troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting) should help you do that.

Comment: I mostly likely should have mentioned this within my first post, but the error ONLY occurs when I attempt to obtain the data contained within the .docx file. Otherwise, the error does not occur. In this case, the .getDataAsString('UTF-8'); is the cause.